# Excel macro formats only the first instance of a repeated value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel makro that looks like this

I expected it to format and left align all instances of *Streckkod* and *Återlämningsdatum*, but it only works for the forst occurrence. What am I doing wrong?

I'm just a copy-paste programmer and this is the second time I have tried to do something with vba, so any help will be appreciated

```
Sub Transform()
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim s As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Double
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wshS = ActiveSheet
    wshS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=wshS.Range("A1"), Header:=xlYes
    m = wshS.Range("A" & wshS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For s = 2 To m
        If s > 2 Then
            t = t + 2
            wshT.Cells(t, 1).Value = "total price"
            wshT.Cells(t, 2).Value = d
        End If
        If wshS.Range("A" & s).Value <> wshS.Range("A" & s - 1).Value Then
            Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            For c = 1 To 1
                wshT.Cells(c, 1).Value = wshS.Cells(1, c).Value
                wshT.Cells(c, 2).Value = wshS.Cells(s, c).Value
                wshT.Cells(c, 2).NumberFormat = "0000000000"
                wshT.Cells(c, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                'Personnummer
            Next c
            t = 1
            d = 0

            For c = 2 To 5
                wshT.Cells(c, 1).Value = wshS.Cells(1, c).Value
                wshT.Cells(c, 2).Value = wshS.Cells(s, c).Value
            Next c
            t = 5
            d = 0
        End If

        t = t + 1
        For c = 6 To 8
            t = t + 1
            wshT.Cells(t, 1).Value = wshS.Cells(1, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(t, 2).Value = wshS.Cells(s, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(c, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wshT.Cells(c, 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next c

        For c = 9 To 9
            t = t + 1
            wshT.Cells(t, 1).Value = wshS.Cells(1, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(t, 2).Value = wshS.Cells(s, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(c, 2).NumberFormat = "0000000000000"
            wshT.Cells(c, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            'Streckkod

        Next c

        For c = 10 To 10
            t = t + 1
            wshT.Cells(t, 1).Value = wshS.Cells(1, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(t, 2).Value = wshS.Cells(s, c).Value
            wshT.Cells(c, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
            wshT.Cells(c, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            'återlämningsdatum

        Next c


        d = d + wshS.Cells(s, 10).Value
    Next s



    ' Last total
    t = t + 2
    wshT.Cells(t, 1).Value = "total price"
    wshT.Cells(t, 2).Value = d


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Could you not just keep the Streckkod use For c = 9 To 10 and remove the second 'återlämningsdatum part?

Comment: That would give a cleaner code for the first loop, but not affect the following instances